# SQL query convert to array Android

Tags: android

Hello i am new in android and i really need help with something. I got a prepopulate database in my sqlitehelper class and i need a query request returns a String[] table. 
Example my database got 3 columns id, name, tel my query will be based on id so the cursor will get {1 mary 2134} i want that to be converted to an String [1 mary 2134]. Dont know if it helps but all my requests will be getting a single row returned, cause the query its primary key based.
my code is something like that:

```
   public String[] getSingleRow(String id){
    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TELEPHONE}
    Cursor cursor = this.dbSqlite.query(TABLE_NAME, asColumnsToReturn, COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);


    //here is where i need help
    String table[]=new String[2];
    int i = 0;

                while (i < table.length) {
                table[i]  = cursor.getString(i);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
return table;
  }
```

I need that so in my main class i can set textview like:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Table= SQLiteHelper.getSingleRow(id);
myTextView.setText(Table[0]); // "0"for id "1" for name and "2" for telephone
```

So my question is how do i convert a single row returned query to a String[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused on what a cursor is.

A cursor points to one row in your results response. So if your table looks like this:

```
1 | Mary | 1234
2 | Alice | 134
3 | Bob | 123
```

The cursor can only point to one of these rows at a time until you call cursor.movetoNext(). In a single row result, your cursor obviously will never have to use that method.

Of course, if you want a single ROW and not a TABLE like your variable is named:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String row[] = new String[3]
row[0] = cursor.getString(0);
row[1] = cursor.getString(1);
row[2] = cursor.getString(2);
return row;
```

Also, I would suggest using constants for the columns as well:

```
//declared somewhere as public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexByName(KEY_NAME));
```

Comment: Wow that was fast... thanks that was exactly what i wanted i just put it in a for loop and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use a cursor you have to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` first. Call this before your while loop.